# why it is "incorrect (no strata)" in adonis?

Tags: r, vegan

I am learning how to do `PERMANOVA`, it is really a challenge when I started from the example. The following code is from the help page in `adonis`. I can go through the example, but can't figure out why it is `incorrect (no strata)`?  Does that mean I have to obtain strata data to use `adonis`?

```
data(dune)
data(dune.env)

### Example of use with strata, for nested (e.g., block) designs.
dat <- expand.grid(rep=gl(2,1), NO3=factor(c(0,10)),field=gl(3,1) )
Agropyron <- with(dat, as.numeric(field) + as.numeric(NO3)+2) +rnorm(12)/2
Schizachyrium <- with(dat, as.numeric(field)-as.numeric(NO3)+2) +rnorm(12)/2
Y <- data.frame(Agropyron, Schizachyrium)
mod <- metaMDS(Y)
plot(mod)

### Hulls show treatment
with(dat, ordihull(mod, group=NO3, show="0"))
with(dat, ordihull(mod, group=NO3, show="10", col=3))

### Spider shows fields
with(dat, ordispider(mod, group=field, lty=3, col="red"))

### Correct hypothesis test (with strata)
adonis(Y ~ NO3, data=dat, strata=dat$field, perm=999)

### Incorrect (no strata)
adonis(Y ~ NO3, data=dat, perm=999)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `PERMANOVA`, the `PER` bit stands for **permutation** tests. Permutation tests are only valid if you shuffle samples that are truly exchangeable under the experimental design of the study. In this instance, the example uses a blocked study and hence the permutation test is *only* valid if you permute sample *within* the levels of `strata` and never between the levels of `strata`.

That's what the comment `Incorrect (no strata)` refers to; that the unrestricted permutation test for *these* data is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks, Gavin.  Is it **the original design of the study** that does not allow the permutation test between the levels of `strata`?      I looked into the `dat <- expand.grid(rep=gl(2,1), NO3=factor(c(0,10)),field=gl(3,1) )`. According to the `rep` variable in `dat`, it seems that there were repeated measurements in three fields. Is my understanding right? I am not sure what is blocked study.